# analysis Quantity in market basket analysis

Tags: data-mining, apriori

In market basket analysis

is it effect Qty in analysis for example

example 1:

T1=A,B,C

T2=A,A,b

T3=A,b,b,c

Example 2:

T1=A,B,C

T2=A,b

T3=A,b,c

result is same for two example or not

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your data encoding.

If you encode the itemsets as classic sets, then you have "sets".

If you encode as a1, a2, a3, ... then you can get some quantities.

Comment: Is there any way to do market basket analysis that uses quantities without having to encode them? For data with high sales volumes, e.g. thousands of units per customer, I don't think you will find very useful relationships if you encode each unique value. I guess you could encode them by ranges, e.g. 0-999, 1,000-5,000, but that wouldn't get as good results.